# Head() is not showing the result

Tags: python, tail, head

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("stock_data.csv")
df.head()
```

Is not showing the result: suggestion for improvement?

Answer (score 0):

Try printing `df.head()`. In your notebook type:
`print(df.head())`

Answer (score 0):

You need to print df.head:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("stock_data.csv")
print(df.head())
```